# Univariate after stepwise regression?

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, reporting, univariate

My aim is to understand and describe the effect that independent variables (ordered and unordered factors and continuous) have on a continuous dependent variable.

First, I thought about using a stepwise regression with AIC to select the most "important" ones. However, it would be also nice to describe these important independent variables more in detail, like showing a correlation plot for continuous or Tukey test (if the ANOVA was significant) for the factors.

However, I feel it is strange to do univariate analysis after the multivariate. Any recommendation and experience? Which values to report as main findings in a scientific paper? Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in finding the association between a particular independent variable and the outcome, corrected for other variables? In general I would recommend against stepwise regression, since it leads to biased estimates (see e.g. https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-018-0143-6).

Comment: Thanks @Stijn, interesting paper! First I want to find the variables that have an effect on the dependent variable and then somehow analyze these variables and their relations to the dependent in more details (but not those, that don't seem to have an effect). Maybe I should just start with a univariate for all the "candidate".

Comment: Univariate screening is unfortunately quite prevalent in some fields of science but it is not a good variable selection tool. Note that univariate screening is a (worse) type of stepwise selection. See also: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/tri.12895 and https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8699212/

Comment: Besides univariate screening being a disaster of a method, the idea that the data contain sufficient information content to allow one to determine which predictors are important needs to be abandoned.  If you compute bootstrap confidence intervals on the ranks of predictor importance you'll see wider confidence intervals than you would predict.  An example of this is in [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms) - look for "bootstrapping ranks of predictors".

Comment: I'd highly recommend Frank's *Regression Modeling Strategies*. Chapter 4 (at least in the first edition, I believe second edition has similar material in the same chapter) has an excellent discussion of issues with stepwise regression. I'd also suggest taking a look at *Elements of Statistical Learning*.